# Adding c++ to complex C makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I would like to add a cpp file to use the c functions. I made the file but the problem becomes how to include the file in the makefile.All I know is that I should compile with c++ after C. and then link it together.

May someone point me in the right direction.

This is a snippet of testcpp.cpp

```
    extern "C" {
  #include "darknet.h"
}
```

Below is the makefile but i keep getting No rule to make target 'obj/test.cpp', needed by 'darknet'.

```
    GPU=0
CUDNN=0
OPENCV=0
NNPACK=1
NNPACK_FAST=1
ARM_NEON=1
OPENMP=0
DEBUG=0
QPU_GEMM=1

ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
      -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
      -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] \
      -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]
#      -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] \ This one is deprecated?

# This is what I use, uncomment if you know your arch and want to specify
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52

VPATH=./src/:./examples
SLIB=libdarknet.so
ALIB=libdarknet.a
EXEC=darknet
OBJDIR=./obj/

CC=gcc
NVCC=nvcc 
AR=ar
ARFLAGS=rcs
OPTS=-Ofast
LDFLAGS= -lm -pthread 
COMMON= -Iinclude/ -Isrc/
#CFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC
#CFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -march=native -mfpmath=sse
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -mcpu=cortex-a53


ifeq ($(OPENMP), 1) 
CFLAGS+= -fopenmp
endif

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1) 
OPTS=-O0 -g
endif

CFLAGS+=$(OPTS)

ifeq ($(OPENCV), 1) 
COMMON+= -DOPENCV
CFLAGS+= -DOPENCV
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs opencv` 
COMMON+= `pkg-config --cflags opencv` 
endif

ifeq ($(GPU), 1) 
COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
CFLAGS+= -DGPU
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN), 1) 
COMMON+= -DCUDNN 
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN
LDFLAGS+= -lcudnn
endif

ifeq ($(QPU_GEMM), 1) 
COMMON+= -DQPU_GEMM
CFLAGS+= -DQPU_GEMM
LDFLAGS+= -lqmkl
endif

ifeq ($(NNPACK), 1)
COMMON+= -DNNPACK
CFLAGS+= -DNNPACK
LDFLAGS+= -lnnpack -lpthreadpool
endif

ifeq ($(NNPACK_FAST), 1)
COMMON+= -DNNPACK_FAST
CFLAGS+= -DNNPACK_FAST
endif

ifeq ($(ARM_NEON), 1)
COMMON+= -DARM_NEON
CFLAGS+= -DARM_NEON -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -funsafe-math-optimizations -ftree-vectorize
endif

OBJ=gemm.o utils.o cuda.o deconvolutional_layer.o convolutional_layer.o list.o image.o activations.o im2col.o col2im.o blas.o crop_layer.o dropout_layer.o maxpool_layer.o softmax_layer.o data.o matrix.o network.o connected_layer.o cost_layer.o parser.o option_list.o detection_layer.o route_layer.o box.o normalization_layer.o avgpool_layer.o layer.o local_layer.o shortcut_layer.o activation_layer.o rnn_layer.o gru_layer.o crnn_layer.o demo.o batchnorm_layer.o region_layer.o reorg_layer.o tree.o  lstm_layer.o
EXECOBJA=captcha.o lsd.o super.o art.o tag.o cifar.o go.o rnn.o segmenter.o regressor.o classifier.o coco.o yolo.o detector.o nightmare.o attention.o darknet.o
EXECOBJA1=testcpp.cpp
ifeq ($(GPU), 1) 
LDFLAGS+= -lstdc++ 
OBJ+=convolutional_kernels.o deconvolutional_kernels.o activation_kernels.o im2col_kernels.o col2im_kernels.o blas_kernels.o crop_layer_kernels.o dropout_layer_kernels.o maxpool_layer_kernels.o avgpool_layer_kernels.o
endif

EXECOBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(EXECOBJA))
EXECOBJ1 = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(EXECOBJA1))
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ))
DEPS = $(wildcard src/*.h) Makefile include/darknet.h
CPP=g++
#all: obj backup results $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC)
all: obj  results $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC)


$(EXEC): $(EXECOBJ) $(ALIB)
    $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(ALIB)

$(EXEC): $(EXECOBJ1)
    $(CPP) -Wall $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(ALIB): $(OBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

$(SLIB): $(OBJS)
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -shared $^ -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
    $(NVCC) $(ARCH) $(COMMON) --compiler-options "$(CFLAGS)" -c $< -o $@

obj:
    mkdir -p obj
backup:
    mkdir -p backup
results:
    mkdir -p results

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC) $(EXECOBJ)
```

I thought
 `$(EXEC): $(EXECOBJ1)
    $(CPP) -Wall $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)`
would compile the cpp file and

```
$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
$(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

would link it

Comment: "It does not work" is not a proper way to describe a problem

Comment: Apologise about that. I am doing something wrong and I dont know what. Any help?

Comment: Thanks. Just updated.

Comment: Your makefile shows a lot of irrelevant things. But the strangest is how you define the object files ! : you hardcode them, instead of generating them automatically from source files. Checkout the `patsubst` make function.

Comment: Are you sure about the error message ? Sounds odd to me...

Comment: Honestly it is not my makefile. If it was I would understand everything there and be able to add it.

Comment: You need to understand that `Makefile`.  Perhaps using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) with `-x`  could help. Or at least `make --trace`. Take time to read the [documentation of GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). And that `makefile` is not that complex. If you prefer, rewrite it from scratch (or switch to some other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, perhaps [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)...). Be sure to understand how to [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a recipe to compile object files from `.cpp` file:

```
$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

The error you describe probably comes from an incorrect usage of `vpath`: I don't think its usage is necessary here.

But basically I agree with @Basile Starynkevitch : you might be better rewriting from scratch. I have a few suggestions:

1 - Clearly separate in different folders **programs** (C or C++ files that hold a `main()` function) and **library** files (C or C++ files that hold functions). This will be useful for linking.

For example:

```
|
+--lib   // holds "library" code
+--app   // holds programs
+--headers
+--BUILD
    |
    +-- obj
    |    |
    |    +-- app
    |    +-- lib
    |
    +-- bin
```

2 - Automatically generate both object files and programs from source files:

```
SRC_FILES_LIB = $(wildcard lib/*.cpp)
SRC_FILES_APP = $(wildcard app/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES_LIB = $(patsubst lib/%.cpp,BUILD/obj/lib/%.o,$(SRC_FILES_LIB))
OBJ_FILES_APP = $(patsubst app/%.cpp,BUILD/obj/app/%.o,$(SRC_FILES_APP))
EXEC_FILES    = $(patsubst app/%.cpp,BUILD/bin/%,$(SRC_FILES_APP))
```

3 - add a target that builds the programs:

```
all:  $(EXEC_FILES)
    @echo "done"
```

After that, its just a matter of providing the sufficient pattern rule.
(sorry, no more time for that)

Comment: still gives me no rule to target obj/test.cpp. It does not make sense since test.cpp is in examples/.